# JHipster - How to debug in Eclipse only one gateway (or microservice) in a microservices architecture?

Tags: mongodb, eclipse, docker, microservices, jhipster

Assuming that with JHipster I've generated:
- 1 Gateway (with MongoDB + JHipsterRegistry)
- 3 Microservices [called A, B and C] (with MongoDB + JHipsterRegistry)

I'm using maven.

I've composed all in Docker, so the resulting Docker configuration is:

- 1 JHipster Registry
- 1 Gateway
- 1 Gateway MongoDB
- 1 Microservice A
- 1 Microservice A MongoDB
- 1 Microservice B
- 1 Microservice B MongoDB
- 1 Microservice C
- 1 Microservice C MongoDB

All works fine: from the Gateway I can see entities from each Microservice.

Now I need to implement some features on Gateway (UI pages etc), and I need to debug with Eclipse during development.

How can I achieve this?

A) Do I need to run all manually, so running:

- all components manually with ./mvnw
- the JHipsterRegistry from a .jar
- the Gateway from Eclipse running the debugger executing the main Application

B) Or can I use somehow docker for all "static" components and run only the Gateway from eclipse?

C) Any other suggestion?

If (A):

- I need to start also all MongoDB manually?
- How?
- May the used ports collide?
- Do I need to change configurations?

If (B):

- How to run all "static" components in docker?
- How to configure the Gateway to reach other components?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar as follows, duplicate your `docker-compose` directory
create `docker-compose-dev`

edit the new `docker-compose.yml` remove the gateway service

edit your hosts file create an entry as follows:
`127.0.0.1              jhipster-registry`

run this setup `docker compose up -d`
It should start without issues then you can run your gateway
from the command line terminals using `mvnw` and `npm start`